# How to insert .html file in outlook as text by using python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I want to insert a .html file as text by using python.
I am using win32com but problem is that it is attaching the file in attachment i want to insert it in main body.

```
import win32com.client
from conf import *
const=win32com.client.constants
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "ST_Report_20" + time.strftime("%y%m%d")
newMail.Body = "Please Find the Report here " + path + "\index.html"

newMail.To = "abc@email.com"
attachment1 = "D:\Work\Report_auto\Report.htm" 

newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
newMail.display()

newMail.send()
```

Comment: What if you try to change the Body Format? 
newMail.BodyFormat
newMail.HTMLBody = mail_body

Comment: @giosans What i give in newMail.HTMLBody = -----  shall I gave the path of HTML file or the code written in it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may need to convert the index.html to string first and concatenate with mail.HTMLBody

```
.....
with open('index.html', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
newMail.HTMLBody = "Please Find the Report here " + data

.....
```

Comment: let me know if this helped you :)

Comment: Hi Arun, This will help me there is one thing to edit I have to use newMail.HTMLBody  Thanks :)

Comment: Could someone please help in case I am using `smtplib` to send the mail using python. And  I want to put the content of the `HTML` file directly in the `body` of the mail not as an attachment? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is using smtplib in that case, we need to use the below snippet:

```
  with open('file.html', 'r') as myfile2:
            data2 = myfile2.read()

        body2 = data2

        message2 = MIMEMultipart()
        message2["From"] = abc@outlook.com
        message2["To"] = ", ".join(recipients)
        message2["Subject"] = "Your subject"

        message2.attach(MIMEText(body2, "html"))
        #message2.set_payload(body2) ## it is for text
        session2 = self.create_session(config_details)
        session2.sendmail(config_details[0], self.recipients, message2.as_string())
        session2.quit();
```